# How to use WSO2 AM to call my backend services that are secured with OATH

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

Using  my API Gateway WSO2, I want to call my backend services (my endpoints) that are secured with OAuth (ACCES-Token). But I cannot find how to do that.

It's even mentioned on the WSO2 website that by using API publisher (of WSO2 AM) you can only configure your APIs to call services secured with username/password : https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM210/Working+with+Endpoints

*You cannot call backend services secured with OAuth through APIs created in the API Publisher. At the moment, you can call only services secured with username/password.*

Do you know if there is another way to do this without using the API Publisher ?

Mu browser (SET API Gateway Access-Token) -- API Gatewau WSO2 (**SET my Backend services Acess-Token**) --> My backend services

Thank you !

Comment: the access token you sent to the AM it´s the same you send to the BE API?

Answer (score 0):

> You cannot call backend services secured with OAuth through APIs created in the API Publisher. At the moment, you can call only services secured with username/password.

Out-of-box from the API Publisher you can directly authenticate with the backend using Basic authentication (username and  password)

> Do you know if there is another way to do this without using the API Publisher ?

well - the Publisher app is always involved

> I want to call my backend services (my endpoints) that are secured with OAuth (ACCES-Token)

There are multiple ways how to authenticate with the backend, not all are so straightforward

1. Basic authentication (this is what you don't want)
2. JWT token - the API Manager is able to send a signed JWT token with the API calls to the backend and the backend service could authenticate and extract client details from the JWT token.
3. Using the inbound mediation configuration you could manipulate the request payload and metadata

With the point 3 you should be able to send a custom OAuth/Authorization header. The question is - with what identity provider your service is authenticating/authorizing?

The problem is that there's no unified configuration how your service's client (API manager calling the backend) would fetch / cache / refresh / revoke the token which would work with all possible identity providers.

In theory you could implement the OAuth authentication with external IdP using the inbound mediations (sequences), but I strongly urge do not put anything complex as API mediation for sake of maintainability (been there, done that, screw it badly)

Maybe the simplest option would be having a permanent token you could [pass in the HTTP headers](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB500/Header+Mediator), it sounds simple enough.

Answer (score 0):

There is a custom Oauth2 mediator which you can try. https://github.com/imesh/wso2-oauth-mediator